# How to respond to Slack thread with curl command

Tags: curl, slack, slack-api

I am trying to get my curl to work then i try to create a response to a thread.

I have been following this doc:
https://api.slack.com/docs/message-threading#threads_party
And from the tester I got the information required to make the call:
https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage/test

If I try to make a curl looking like this:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"token":"MYTOKEN","channel":"Chanel-ID", "message": {"text":"curl", "thread_ts":"1543586718.000800"}}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/MYSLACKHOOKID
```

Everytime I do this, I get the response "No-text", can someone help me on the way to my goal, All i wanna do is making a respond to a message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of issues in your curl statement.

1. Incoming webhooks do not support threads, so you need to use the `chat.postMessage` API method instead. As stated in the [documentation](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-threading#threads_party):

   > Incoming webhooks do not support threads. If you want your app to
   >   respond with a message in a thread, use chat.postMessage.
2. The syntax of your JSON is not correct. there is no `message` property. Instead make one flat JSON array with all needed properties (except `token`), e.g. `channel`, `text`, `thread_ts`. See here for full syntax of [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage)
3. When posting as JSON you must include your token in the authorization header, not in the body of your request. As explained [here](https://api.slack.com/web#posting_json) in more detail.
4. Last, but not least I would recommend to specify the charset or you will get a warning.

The complete curl looks like this:

```
curl https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8' -H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" --data '{"channel":"CHANNEL-ID", "text":"curl", "thread_ts":"THREAD-TS"}'
```